# Is it possible/useful to transpile Scala to golang?

Tags: scala, go, scala-native

Scala native has been recently released, but the garbage collector they used (for now) is extremely [rudimentary](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11679012) and makes it not suitable for serious use.

So I wonder: why not just **transpile Scala to Go** (a la Scala.js)? It's going to be a fast, portable runtime. And their GC is getting better and better. Not to mention the inheritance of a great concurrency model: channels and goroutines.

- So why did scala-native choose to go so low level with LLVM?
- What would be the catch with a golang transpiler?

Comment: It's pretty early days for scala-native, and clearly they're kinda spoiled with the JVM's GC, it'll take some optimizing for sure. But the main reason is that llvm is an insanely good language for writing languages. IIUC llvm will ship with some native gc options in future versions.

Comment: About usefulness: java is already "a fast, portable" runtime targeted by Scala, proven in mission critical applications for decades. So what would be the benefit?

Comment: Startup time and memory footprint for small apps. In other words: systems programming.

Answer (score 21):

There are two kinds of languages that are good targets for compilers:

1. Languages whose semantics closely match the source language's semantics.
2. Languages which have very low-level and thus very general semantics (or one might argue: no semantics at all).

Examples for #1 include: compiling [ECMAScript 2015 to ECMAScript 5](https://babeljs.io/) (most language additions were specifically designed as syntactic sugar for existing features, you just have to desugar them), compiling [CoffeeScript to ECMAScript](http://coffeescript.org/), compiling [TypeScript to ECMAScript](https://typescriptlang.org/) (basically, after type checking, just erase the types and you are done), compiling [Java to JVM byte code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/file/default/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac), compiling [C♯ to CLI CIL bytecode](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp), compiling [Python to CPython bytecode](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Python/compile.c), compiling [Python to PyPy bytecode](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/pypy/interpreter/astcompiler/codegen.py), compiling [Ruby to YARV bytecode](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/compile.c), compiling [Ruby to Rubinius bytecode](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/tree/master/lib/rubinius/code/compiler), compiling [ECMAScript to SpiderMonkey bytecode](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src).

Examples for #2 include: machine code for a general purpose CPU ([RISC even more so](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/)), [C--](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/c--/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/).

Compiling Scala to Go fits neither of the two. Their semantics are *very* different.

You need either a language with powerful low-level semantics as the target language, so that you can *build* your own semantics *on top*, or you need a language with closely matching semantics, so that you can *map* your own semantics *into* the target language.

In fact, even JVM bytecode is already *too* high-level! It has constructs such as classes that do not match constructs such as Scala's traits, so there has to be a fairly complex encoding of traits into classes and interfaces. Likewise, before `invokedynamic`, it was actually pretty much impossible to represent dynamic dispatch on structural types in JVM bytecode. The Scala compiler had to resort to reflection, or in other words, deliberately stepping *outside* of the semantics of JVM bytecode (which resulted in a terrible performance overhead for method dispatch on structural types compared to method dispatch on other class types, even though both are the *exact same thing*).

Proper Tail Calls are another example: we would like to have them in Scala, but because JVM bytecode is not powerful enough to express them without a *very* complex mapping (basically, you have to forego using the JVM's call stack altogether and manage your own stack, which destroys both performance and Java interoperability), it was decided to not have them in the language.

Go has some of the same problems: in order to implement Scala's expressive non-local control-flow constructs such as exceptions or threads, we need an equally expressive non-local control-flow construct to map to. For *typical* target languages, this "expressive non-local control-flow construct" is either continuations or the venerable `GOTO`. Go *has* [`GOTO`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements), but it is deliberately limited in its "non-localness". For *writing* code by humans, limiting the expressive power of `GOTO` is a good thing, but for a compiler target language, not so much.

It is very likely possible to rig up powerful control-flow using goroutines and channels, but now we are already leaving the comfortable confines of just mapping Scala semantics to Go semantics, and start building Scala high-level semantics on top of Go high-level semantics that weren't designed for such usage. Goroutines weren't designed as a general control-flow construct to build other kinds of control-flow on top of. That's not what they're good at!

> So why did scala-native choose to go so low level with LLVM?

Because that's precisely what LLVM was designed for and is good at.

> What would be the catch with a golang transpiler?

The semantics of the two languages are too different for a direct mapping and Go's semantics are not designed for building different language semantics on top of.

> their GC is getting better and better

So can Scala-native's. As far as I understand, the choice for current use of Boehm-Dehmers-Weiser is basically one of laziness: it's there, it works, you can drop it into your code and it'll just do its thing.

Note that changing the GC is [under discussion](https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native/issues/128). There are other GCs which are designed as drop-ins rather than being tightly coupled to the host VM's object layout. E.g. IBM is currently in the process of re-structuring J9, their high-performance JVM, into a set of loosely coupled, independently re-usable "runtime building blocks" components and releasing them under a permissive open source license.

The project is called ["Eclipse OMR"](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/omr) ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/omr)) and it is already production-ready: the Java 8 implementation of IBM J9 was built completely out of OMR components. There is a [Ruby + OMR](https://github.com/rubyomr-preview/) project which demonstrates how the components can easily be integrated into an existing language runtime, because the components themselves assume no language semantics and no specific memory or object layout. The [commit](https://github.com/rubyomr-preview/ruby/commit/0110934eb31edbacf1888eeaeb967e7f66171b43) which swaps out the GC and adds a JIT and a profiler clocks in at just over 10000 lines. It isn't production-ready, but it boots and runs Rails. They also have a similar project for CPython (not public yet).

> why not just transpile Scala to Go (a la Scala.js)?

Note that Scala.JS has a lot of the same problems I mentioned above. But they are doing it anyway, because the gain is *huge*: you get access to every web browser on the planet. There is no comparable gain for a hypothetical Scala.go.

There's a reason why there are initiatives for getting low-level semantics into the browser such as [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) and [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.github.io/), precisely because compiling a high-level language to another high-level language always has this "semantic gap" you need to overcome.

In fact, note that even for lowish-level languages that were specifically designed as compilation targets for a specific language, you can still run into trouble. E.g. Java has generics, JVM bytecode doesn't. Java has inner classes, JVM bytecode doesn't. Java has anonymous classes, JVM bytecode doesn't. All of these have to be encoded somehow, and specifically the encoding (or rather non-encoding) of generics has caused all sorts of pain.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation why Scala Native compiles to LLVM and not Go.

Comment: The fact that JVM bytecode doesn't have generics has also made it possible for Scala to have a richer type system than Java, I think.

Comment: @Jasper-M: There was a (now abandoned) .NET implementation of Scala. .NET has reified generics in the VM. AFAIK, that didn't pose problems for Scala, since the Scala Language Specification says that generics are erased anyway. I don't think that is a restriction. It might make it harder to integrate with third-party .NET libraries, though, which is a core *goal* of Scala, but it does not restrict the core *semantics* of Scala. Note, however, that Scala.NET was abandoned quite some time ago, and the type system has changed since then, so maybe you are right, and it would be a problem today.

Comment: I thought the reified generics were part of the reason it got abandoned. But I may be mistaken.